# How to increase width and height on click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to increase height actually to increase bottom and top of div each for 25px also left and right side each for 25px.I don't now is that even possible.

So this is just example but it is similar to my code:

```js
function increaseDiv() {
var myDiv = document.querySelector(".box")
var currWidth = myDiv.clientWidth;
myDiv.style.width = currWidth + 100 + "px";
}
```

```css
.box {
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
position: absolute;
left: 100px;
background: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<button onclick="increaseDiv()">Click</button>
```

Here is demo https://jsfiddle.net/SutonJ/0pdwm39a/14/

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: How to add to do all left sides 25px

Comment: How many left sides are there? Please clarify the problem.

Comment: @Suton7 your JSFiddle seems to be expanding the div without issue. You are asking about 25px expansions but your code has 100px written in it, I am still not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: @gru Sorry I thought four sides

Comment: @maksymiuk I know that is just example.Answer down is correct but I need this to happened every time when I click a button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that position of your div are related to left side and this is why it looks like you increase only the right side; try to add positioning with transform by center or make it by flex(align-items + justify-content)

```
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background: black;
}
```

Comment: @Suton7 This answer should do exactly what you need. You might want to adjust the `left` and `top` position so that the origin of the transformation is where you want it to be. If you want it to remain where it really is in your example, then `left` is simply `calc(100px + 150px)` (left + half width), and `top` is simply `calc(0px + 50%)`

Answer (score 1):

What about CSS [scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/scale())?

That will keep the actual position of the element and expand it in all directions, unless you specify a [transform-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin) value.

Edited with an ever growing effect...

```js
let myDiv = document.querySelector(".box");
let orgiSize = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width;
let increments = 0;

function increaseDiv() {
  increments += 50; // That is 25px on both sides...

  // Make the math here
  var percentage = Math.floor((orgiSize + increments) / orgiSize * 100) / 100

  console.log(percentage);
  myDiv.style.transform = `scale(${percentage})`; // That is a percentage value
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  background: black;
}


/* for the demo */

button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<button onclick="increaseDiv()">Click</button>
```

Comment: It works only the first time.

Comment: Sure... The second time, the element is already scaled. Do you want it to scale more on each click?

Comment: Also even if you scale by 1.25x after each click, and since this is multiplicative it doesn't increase the div size by 50px after the first click.

Comment: The scale coefficient could be calculated as `(width+50)/width`, same for height, and use two parameters `scale(sx,sy)`. It can be a good idea to save current scale to element attribute (or its dataset object), so it doesn't have to be parsed from string every click.

Comment: I want to scale each time when I click button

Comment: I edited with something like I think you wish...

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding you correctly, I think if you changed

```
var currWidth = myDiv.clientWidth;
myDiv.style.width = currWidth + 100 + "px";
```

to

```
var currWidth = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect().width;
myDiv.style.width = currWidth + 50 + "px";
```

and also added

```
var currHeight = myDiv.getBoundingClientRect().height;
myDiv.style.height = currHeight + 50 + "px";
```

I also noticed that your div is using absolute positioning, so you may also need to offset the left and top according to the size change. If you are getting an issue with the actual position when the size changes let me know.